# SQLITE update, limit, case

Tags: sqlite, limit

[image]i want to implement a parking lot application 
so there is a garage with 5 or more parking lots 
when the driver parks his car the next free slot in the garage should be assigned to him.

so i have a table garage with 5 or more slots 
 i have the problem when i update 
                   update garage set free = 0, set car = 1 (car_id) then all free slots are update how can i limit only to update the first free row?

Can anyone help me

thanks in advance (false) 
Thanks
i have garage table with levels and slots in each level when i park a car i want to update just the free slots

[image: table garage]

Comment: You need to have a WHERE clause with criteria which references the row you want to update.

Comment: the only criteria i have is the boolean true or false (free or not free) so there can be multiple rows with free so i cant really limit it just some limit criteria would be appriciated

Comment: Show your table structure.  Sounds like it wasn't designed properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to specify which record(s) you want to update, or the database will update *all* of them. If you're looking to update one record specifically, you might want to reference its `PRIMARY KEY` with a `WHERE` clause.

If you haven't assigned a `PRIMARY KEY` for your table, [you could use SQLite's `rowid` column.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) Something like this:

```
SELECT rowid FROM garage WHERE free = 1;
```

Then, supposing you identify spot 5 is free for car 42:

```
UPDATE garage SET free = 0, car = 42 WHERE rowid = 5;
```

If you prefer, you can combine those two steps into a single query:

```
UPDATE garage SET free=0, car=42 WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM garage WHERE free=1 LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: yeah this is clear but i want to assign the slots dynamically so i dont have to give the slot id but only the free (true, false) column so UPDATE and LIMIT would be an option but it seems some additional effort to enable this on sqlite

Comment: It seems to me that I'd want to know the ID of the parking space I'm calling UPDATE on, but supposing you don't care, it's possible to combine the queries:  `UPDATE garage SET free=0, car=42 WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM garage WHERE free=1 LIMIT 1);`

Comment: the comment from @rutter should be the answer, or at least added to the answer.